# Unable to view geometry with Sverchok

Tags: sverchok

I am trying to get started with parametric 3D modeling, and I am following along with [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tu_31Cigflc). Unfortunately, I cannot get the mesh to show in the 3D viewer. I tried some of the other viewing nodes, but those don't show up either.

[image: Mesh not showing up from temporal viewer]

I am able to generate a mesh using the "BAKE" button, but it's not easy to work blindly (as you can imagine).

[image: BAKE generates the 3D mesh]

Can someone please lend a hand?

Edit: [Here is a link to the .blend file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuDlmeHZST6sggOfoy4DYhpv3D9A?e=HyVQN0)

Comment: i can see your result :  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpbLe.png although it doesn't fit to the image of your question. Did u try an older sverchok version with an older Blender version? Just from my own experience:i also have (installation) problems with the newest Blender file and sverchok - it might be a good idea to ask on their github page